# Run Time of a Process in windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Can I see what a process was started on windows XP?  I don't see it as column in task manager, there another way?

Comment: Is this elapsed time in the performance counters it? 400 mean 400 seconds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this on the command line.

```
wmic process get caption,creationdate
```

Refer to [Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784189%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm... command line ... How did you know that was just what I wanted? :-)

Answer (score 6):

Using [Microsoft/SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), which is a much more full-featured process manager, you can add a Process Start Time column to the basic process list to see the time each process started.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure heavyd's answer is probably right.  But after I asked I found 'Elapsed Time' under the process counter for the particular process in perfmon.  The 'Explain' says:

> "The total elapsed time, in seconds,
>   that this process has been running."